# jquery execute function in all event

Tags: jquery, events, execute

is it possible to execute a function in all events

Comment: mousemove on the whole page? hmm...

Answer (score 3):

To do so, you will most likely have to explicitly specify which events you wish to bind to, unless there is a way to get a list of all event names. Keep in mind different elements have different events as well.

You could do something like this:

```
eventNames = "click mouseenter keyup keydown etc.."; // all events you wish to bind to

yourFunction = function() { };

$(/* selector for your elements */).bind(eventNames, yourFunction);
```

Here is the list of possible event values from the [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind#typedatafn):

> blur, focus, load, resize, scroll,
>   unload, beforeunload, click, dblclick,
>   mousedown, mouseup, mousemove,
>   mouseover, mouseout, mouseenter,
>   mouseleave, change, select,  submit,
>   keydown, keypress, keyup, error